# Store value from HTML link in Django

Tags: html, django, hyperlink

I am a beginner with Django and am trying to figure out a way to store a particular value from a link. I have an HTML table populated with values from a database model and have set each of the results to be a link; as shown below. What I want to do is store the value of the result when it is clicked, so that I can access that particular record from the model on another page.

Basically, each result in the table is a link, and when I click that link I want it to show a different attribute from that model on another page. The link itself is the name of the product and I'd like to show a different attribute from the same model on a different page, such as it's price. Is there any way for this to be done?

```
{% for item in products %}
                <tr id="table_content">
                     <td style="width: 250px">
                       <div id="link-product">
                          <a id= "product-clicked" href="/prod_details/"> 
                             {{ item.product }} 
                          </a> 
                      </div> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical pattern is to add that information to your url and then the view that processes the request knows what information to provide. As one possible example, your href could be:

```
<a id= "product-clicked" href="/prod_details/{{ item.id }}"> 
    {{ item.product }} 
</a>
```

That allows the view to return information related to a product with a particular id. Be sure to read up on extracting patterns (like ids) here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#named-groups